# How do databases on smartphones run?

Tags: android, iphone, database, symbian, smartphone

Im trying to write an article on how databases in modern day smart phones(Android,Symbian,iOS,BlackBerry) operate, however couldn't find any material on the internet, despite searching quite a bit. Any pointers in the form of links or input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they all use [SQLite](http://sqlite.com).

Simply put, it's a serverless SQL database.  Or in other words, a C library that takes SQL commands and returns results as read from (or written on) the data stored in a single file.

It's really compact code and works great when you don't need heavy concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,  could you point me to any information that describes how these different OS's use it based on their architecture?

Comment: @Javier is right. Beside the smartphones use web services to fetch data from web server and use the methods like JSON and XML for parsing which are basically coded in php,.net or some other languages. It helps to fetch data easily from the same. You can easily find different projects or blogs that help to append the same.Thanks.

Comment: Since SQLite is open-source, you can read the source code yourself. http://www.sqlite.org/ Or maybe they have some documentation there about the design.

Comment: @morningstar, their documentattion says nothing about different architectures for different platforms

Comment: @KodeSeeker: i don't get what you're asking; at the C level, they're all the same.

Comment: @Javier : I was asking  how do different mobile systems(Android,Iphone) etc vary in implementing the same thing, if at all.

Comment: @KodeSeeker So SQLite is a C library. C pretty much works everywhere because everything (almost) builds on top of it. All the phones will work off the base C project, however since each platform uses its own preferred language (e.g. obj-c on iphone), I would guess that in those cases sqlite wrappers will be used - http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers. But again, all the wrappers are based of the main C project therefore the implementations and the functionality are identical on all devices as long as the device supports sqlite.